# AngularJS DOM Access On Init

Tags: angularjs

I wrote this simple jsfiddle in which I do (successfully) some basic addClass on a directive in a ng-repeat.

http://jsfiddle.net/rv6u2/5/

Now, my question is: which is the best (*or intended*) place to do such DOM manipulations:

**A. In the directive?**

**B. In the controller?**

Both possibilities are shown in my example.

**Code:**

```
var TestApp = angular.module("TestApp", ['ngResource']);
TestApp.directive('onLoad', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            elm.addClass('loaded'); // A: DOM manipulation in directive
            scope.initMe(scope.$eval(attrs.onLoad2), elm); // B: DOM manipulation handled in controller
        }
    };
});
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NEVER** manipulate the dom inside of controllers.

Controllers should just use services and update attributes of $scope. All DOM manipulation should be made by directives and(in some cases) services(e.g. [$anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll))

See the concepts of angularjs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts)

**UPDATE**: Example of the correct way [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rv6u2/8/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. Although i know the doc of angularjs this was something i did not know (but suspected to be like this).

Comment: If you wouldnt mind, please add a fiddle with the correct way in your answer so others with my question can learn too.

Comment: I've updated the example with just the directive way. About the `bind("load"`, if you expect the DOM to fire it after being created, yes, is redundant, because to attach an event it need to be already created(and in the link function it is already inserted in the page). But if is a custom event fired by a jquery plugin or something else it make sense(just remeber about scope.$apply).

Answer (score 2):

A more "Angular way" of setting class loaded2 would be as follows (which avoids DOM manipulation inside the controller):

In the HTML, declare a model for the class (myClass):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="item" on-load="initMe(item)" ng-class="myClass">
```

In the link function, just call the controller method:

```
scope.initMe()
```

In the controller, manipulate the model/$scope property:

```
$scope.initMe = function() {
   $scope.myClass = "loaded2";
}
```

Changing the model/scope will automatically update the view.

This method is useful if you want to declare in the HTML that a class is being controlled by $scope property myClass.  However, using elm.addClass() inside the linking function is more self-contained and easier to maintain (and I like that approach better).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My point wasnt to set Classes i know its a bad bad example i picked ^^. My point was to manipulate dom, whilst knowing about the model. (I initialized a jquery Image Upload Plugin). Anyways i ended up doing it in the directive.